# Shortkey to open current explorer window again

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Many times I need to switch between windows, but instead of opening the folder manually, I was looking for a short-key to open the open window again. Is there a short-key for that? If yes, what is it?

Comment: Are you asking how to navigate to to an already open Window? Are you asking how to "duplicate" the currently selected open window?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update** based upon comments by OP

You can do this with the mouse. Right click on the directory and select Open in new window.

Or, for a short cut with keyboard, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Original answer below

---

Your question is not clear.

If you want to navigate to an already open Window, then use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

However, if you want a short cut to any specific directory, then I don't think you can but there is possibly a work around to this (depending on your situation it may or may not be feasible).

You can assign global commands to shortcuts. So, create a shortcut to My Documents, and save it to your desktop. Right click on this short cut and select properties. Under the shortcut tab you can type in a letter in the Shortcut key box

For example, I typed G and it shows

[image]

Now, I just type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and that directory loads up.

Comment: This is just for one window, i was looking to just copy the window i've opened at that time and then just use a shortkey to duplicate it

Comment: I suggest you [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/699163/edit) as your comment about duplicating it is IMO clearer than the original question @joostmakaay

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 7, simple click: Ctrl + N

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on the environment you're working on, right? 
In the most popular linux desktops you can configure it easily in the keyboard configuration.
Particularly in Gnome (3 and higher) you can go to system-settings > keyboard > shortcuts and set up a custom shortcut with the entry "nautilus" on it, and the combination of your choice. I use `[Super]+E` (widows key + e) which, by the way, is the shortcut that open the *file explorer* on Windows (system in which that key combination works out of the box since XP to 8.1).

In short:
in windows [windows key] + E
In Linux, it will depend but you can configure it on the keyboard setting.   If you use gnome, then the command to launch the file explorer will be "nautilus"; in Kde "dolphin", etc.

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Hmm that opens a new window at 'My Computer', not what i was exactly looking for. But thanks anyway

Comment: Hmm that opens a new window at 'My Computer', not what i was exactly looking for. I mean the window (like 'My Documents') and when i press the shortkey it will open 'my documents again'.

Comment: How does explaining how other OS's help? All you've said is Windows key + E which launches Explorer which may or may not have anything to do with the 'current' window.

Comment: The thing is... **I don't use windows**, and aynway, the *current* window totally depends on the system. Plus the picture wasn't there when I answered. SO I din't knew that he was referring to windows, otherwise I woudn't wrote that response.

Comment: The original tag was Windows Explorer. You can see the full revision history on each question. If you don't use Windows, and don't know the answer, then maybe best not to provide one. There are many 'Nix questions here which need answering though :)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-K, or Right click the tab and select Duplicate Tab.