# Shortcut to re-open windows explorer at current path, and split-screen left/right

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

checking folders and transferring files I often find myself wanting to duplicate the current windows-explorer window and make both former and duplicated explorer window in split screen (left half/right half).

This question was already asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/699163/shortkey-to-open-current-explorer-window-again) 7 years ago for just opening a new explorer window at current path, but I want to ask if there is a faster way of achieving splitscreen view with a duplicated windows explorer window than `crtl+N` (which also takes a surprisingly long time on my machine, 1-2s) and dragging both windows to the left/right desktop borders.

Thanks

Comment: this has gotten a bit more relevant since screens have gotten larger and especially wider

Comment: Instead of dragging the window to the side you could also use WIN + arrow keys to place the window. That would be a little bit faster as you already have your hands on the keyboard when you press CTRL+N

Comment: You could use a dual-pane Explorer replacement.